# Trying to get values from two different table of database by multithreading in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I am new to multithreading and I am trying to get value from two different tables of database through multithreading but i am getting an error of thread safe. below is my code.

```
                object questionList = null;
                object subjectList = null;
                Thread t1 = new Thread(() => {
                    questionList = _context._Question.Where(Question => Question.Prof_ID == id && Question.Isverified == "No").ToList();
                });
                Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    subjectList = _context._Subjects.ToList();
                });
                t1.Start();
                t2.Start();
                t1.Join();
                t2.Join();
```

Belwo is the error i am getting.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. 
Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'
```

Why I am getting this error and how can i resolve it. How can i get value from 2 different table of database? Thanks

Comment: use async await and `ToListAsync`. do not create new threads. DbContext is not thread safe. you would need separate instance

Comment: can you provide me an example, please?

Comment: Need more details about what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: alright. I am  trying to getting values from two different tables. but i dont want it to be done by main thread thats why i created two different threads. And _context is my connection to that respective database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DbContext` is not thread safe, hence the errors

Use async-await and `.ToListAsync()` to make non blocking calls to the database.

```
public async Task MyMethod() {

    //...

    questionList = await _context._Question
        .Where(Question => Question.Prof_ID == id && Question.Isverified == "No")
        .ToListAsync();

    subjectList = await _context._Subjects.ToListAsync();

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets might be usefull as well "MultipleActiveResultSets=True"